# Terminology for SD Card Status

Tags: android, sd-card, fragmentation

We've developed an Android program that relies on access to a particular directory on the SD card. Our program detects whether the SD card is available to the phone, and displays an error message to the user if it's not. The most common use case that will trigger this error is having the device plugged into a computer and having the SD card mounted to the computer.

We're working on the error message, which will instruct the user to make sure the SD card is available to the phone.

Unfortunately, it appears that each phone manufacturer has their own terminology for whether the SD card is available to the phone and how to mount/unmount it. For example, (some?) Samsung devices display a screen with a Mount/Unmount button. The HTC Thunderbolt has a menu one of whose options is "Charge Only". Motorola devices seem split between the Samsung-like behavior and the HTC Thunderbolt-like behavior. The XOOM is it's whole own contraption.

So, two questions:

Is there a common correct terminology that will communicate to the user that they should make the SD card available to the device instead of available to the computer?

If there's not a good common terminology, is there a way to determine what sort of device we're running on and tailor our error message to the particular device's terminology?

Answer (score 1):

"Please remove all usb peripherals (exc chargers) for this app to work"?

NB. (when its mounted but they think its just a charger they will eventually remove it to see if it works anyway!)

Otherwise:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Check out [BRAND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#BRAND) or [MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) or a combination of them plus others ([MODEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) == 'XOOM' maybe?)

```
 if("Motorola".equals(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)){ // or .contains or .starts with etc
// Do stuff     
 }
```

You may want to do some testing as it may return "Mtrla" or "MotorolaChina" etc..

Comment: That's an interesting thought - we don't necessarily want to make them unplug the cable, we just want them to unmount (?) the sd-card.

Comment: But thats the fastest way to make them unmount ;-)